# Does Apache Kylin support querying struct type?

Tags: kylin

I finished the sample cube 
http://kylin.apache.org/docs/tutorial/kylin_sample.html. But this data structure is very basic. I'm wondering can query work for a struct type field by using `.`?

for example, car (`struct`) has name, so can I run the following query ?

```sql
SELECT car.name from example group by car.name
```

Answer (score 0):

so currently it cannot, It supports SQL ANSI-92.

Source code:
https://github.com/apache/kylin/blob/kylin-3.0.0-alpha/core-metadata/src/main/java/org/apache/kylin/metadata/datatype/DataType.java

Comment: There is a document about the SQL that Kylin supports. http://kylin.apache.org/docs/tutorial/sql_reference.html
There is a document about FAQ. http://kylin.apache.org/docs/gettingstarted/faq.html